# Removing spaces around text in a TextButton

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Material 3 `TextButton` to implement a button with **Skip** to another screen function and **Maybe Later** when refusing a subscription. App design guidelines require it to be aligned to the right, giving it a visually pleasing effect. With a regular text, that is not an issue but when using a `TextButton` I've discovered that there is extra space. I can't seem to find how to control that space.

Next I use 2 different background colours to highlight the separation between side margin (black) and content area (grey).

Here is my current result, on top a purple `TextButton` and on the bottom expected result achieved with a `Text`. As you can see, there is still space on the right for the `TextButton` but `Text` is clean. The code follows:

[image: TextButton vs Text]

```
TextButton(
    modifier = modifier
        .height(48.dp)
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.CenterEnd),
    elevation = null,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(
        start = 12.dp,
        top = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding.calculateTopPadding(),
        end = 0.dp,
        bottom = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding.calculateBottomPadding()
    ),
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
) {
    Text(
        text ="Skip",
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        lineHeight = 16.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.End,
        fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
        modifier = modifier.padding(0.dp)
    )
}
```

I have removed padding and content padding but still no luck. An unusual fact is that if I simply change the text it might align to the side margin. Here is an example with 2 `TextButtons`s.

[image: Two buttons]

I guess that there is some size calculation happening behind the scenes that I am not aware of.

Anyhow, if I use a `TextButton` with `Modifier.padding(0.dp)` I get this in preview, 3 different regions of space. How can I remove each of them separately?

[image: Regions]

Answer (score 1):

To remove the extra padding (in `androidx.compose.material3`) and size space:

1. Use [`defaultMinSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).defaultMinSize(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) with value as `1.dp` (passing 0 will have no effect)
2. Most of the views have minimum touch size so `minimumTouchTargetSize` can be updated using a custom [CompositionLocalProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/CompositionLocal). Create a custom `zeroMinTouchSizeConfig` using the current view config as:

```
fun zeroMinTouchSizeConfig(viewConfiguration: ViewConfiguration): ViewConfiguration {
    return object : ViewConfiguration {
        override val longPressTimeoutMillis: Long
            get() = viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis
        override val doubleTapTimeoutMillis: Long
            get() = viewConfiguration.doubleTapTimeoutMillis
        override val doubleTapMinTimeMillis: Long
            get() = viewConfiguration.doubleTapMinTimeMillis
        override val touchSlop: Float
            get() = viewConfiguration.touchSlop
        override val minimumTouchTargetSize: DpSize
            // Zero size for views
            get() = DpSize.Zero
    }
}
```

3. Use `zeroMinTouchSizeConfig` with `CompositionLocalProvider` as:

```
val zeroMinTouchSizeConfig = zeroMinTouchSizeConfig(LocalViewConfiguration.current)
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalViewConfiguration provides zeroMinTouchSizeConfig) {
    TextButton(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .padding(0.dp)
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.CenterEnd)
            .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 1.dp, minHeight = 1.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow)
        ,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red),
        elevation = null,
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
    ) {
        Text(
            text ="Skip",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp)
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        )
    }
}
```

Output:

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

Option 2:
Alternately, you can use can use experimental api (**which can be removed in the future** but prefer using first option for compatibility with other attributes and stability):

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NoMinPaddingButton() {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false) {
        TextButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .padding(0.dp)
                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.CenterEnd)
                .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 1.dp, minHeight = 1.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
            ,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
            border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Red),
            elevation = null,
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        ) {
            Text(
                text ="Skip",
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(0.dp)
                    .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                    .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still has this extra space that I can't get rid of. Basically it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @shadox I have updated the answer with min size changes, TAL. (not sure why my previous comment has been removed. I think it is important for the new readers and OP to go though changes)